# Ask clarification definition of two types of error

Tags: probability, statistics, definition, statistical-inference

In George Casella textbook page 383, it said we have: $P_\theta(\textbf{X}\in R) = $
probability of a type I error if $\theta\in \Theta_0$;

= one minus the probability of a Type II error if $\theta\in \Theta_0^c$.

I am confused here. So the sum of type I error and type II error is equal to 1? Please correct my mistakes.

Comment: But they're Type I and Type II errors of two different hypotheses, no?

Comment: no, I think they are the same hypothesis.